# Why can't I solve this probability problem using P (AUB) = (P(A) + P(B)) - (P(A) X P(B))?

Tags: probability

In a bag there are 3 orange marbles, 4 blue marbles and 5 green marbles. 4. What is the probability of blindly reaching in the bag and pulling out a not-blue and not-orange marble?.

I know the answer is 8/12 or 2/3. My question is why this problem can't be solve using this way:

not blue   = green (5) + orange (3) = 8, the probability is 8/12
not orange = green (5) + blue (4)   = 9, the probability is 9/12

then the probability of blindly reaching in the bag and pulling out a not-blue and not-orange marble is (8/12 + 9/12) - (8/12 x 9/12) = 11/12.

I would be grateful for the explanations.

Comment: After you take out the first marble, won't the individual probabilities change for each colour?

Comment: still beyond my reasoning. any suggestion (pdfs or webs) on what to read to improve my reasoning on basic probability? thanks

Comment: What he means to say is that after you take out the first marble, there are now 11 in the bag, so the probabilities change when you take out the 2nd marble.

Comment: I think the problem may be poorly stated by OP.. the way you have it stated makes it sound like you're choosing two marbles, however in the answer below, it is assumed you're choosing one marble that is neither blue nor orange. I can see it being interpreted both ways.

Comment: I mean I just choose one marble

Comment: If thats the case, you're thinking of the inclusion/exclusion principle wrong. Think of it as $P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)$. If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then $P(A and B) = P(A)P(B)$. The issue with this is that for you, "not blue and not orange" simply means "green", so its a poor application to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

We have $12$ marbles total. We know that the probability of picking a not-blue marble is $2/3$ and the probability of picking not-orange marble is $3/4$. Now since we are looking at the case where we don't pick an orange or blue marble then the outcomes desired are picking a green marble. In probability we have this equation:

$$\frac{\text{outcomes desired}}{\text{total possible outcomes}}$$

Hopefully this helps guide you to your answer.

Comment: Doesn't this give 5/12 since there are 5 marbles that are not blue and not orange?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty confident that is the answer. Since one could ask well what is the probability of not orange then that would be all the blue and green balls divided by total number of balls.